# i wanna publish a Adc potentiometer from a ADS1115 modue value with a ros2 python pubsub Node

Tags: ros2, python

i need to publish a integer from a ros2 talker node with a ads1115  to control a led in a listener node in python like this :

import time
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from time import sleep
from std_msgs.msg import String, Int32
#now setup circuitpython gpio
import board
import busio

## now activate ads1115 for the knob

import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1115 as ADS
from adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in import AnalogIn
from adafruit_simplemath import map_range # make the map function working.

## Create the I2C bus

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

## Create the ADC object using the I2C bus

ads = ADS.ADS1115(i2c)

## Create single-ended input on channel 0

chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0)

#chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0, ADS.P1)
pot = int(map_range(chan.value,0,1020,0,100))  #is the mapped value of a potentiometer.

class Adctalk(Node):
def **init**(self):
super().**init**('adctopic')
self.publisher_= self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)
self.Adcpub_= self.create_publisher(Int32,pot, 10) # is the int that need to be publisher(adctalk.py).

```
    timer_period = 0.5
    self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
    self.i = 0

def timer_callback(self):

   
   
    msg = String() 
   
    Adcmsg = Int32() # should turn to a int.
    msg.data= 'adc channel: %d'  % self.i 
    Adcmsg.data= pot
 
  
    self.publisher_.publish(msg)
    self.Adcpub_.publish(Adcmsg.data) # should publish pot value in data
    self.get_logger().info(msg.data) # logs string
    
    self.get_logger().info( Adcmsg.data) # logs pot value
    
    
   
    self.i += 1
```

def main(args=None):
rclpy.init(args=args)

```
adctalk = Adctalk()
rclpy.spin(adctalk)
adctalk.destroy_node
rclpy.shutdown()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
main()

and listener node(adclisten.py):

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from time import sleep
from std_msgs.msg import String
import time
#now setup circuitpython gpio
import board
import digitalio

print("hello blinka!")

led = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D4) # is the led pin
led.direction = digitalio.Direction.OUTPUT

## was a button setup ignore that

## button = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D18)

## button.direction = digitalio.Direction.INPUT

## button.pull = digitalio.Pull.DOWN

class MinimalSubscriber(Node):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__('adctopic')
    self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
        String,
        'topic',
        self.listener_callback,
        10)
    self.subscription  # prevent unused variable warning

def listener_callback(self, msg,Adcmsg):
    self.get_logger().info('I heard: "%s"' % msg.data)
    self.get_logger().info('I Adcvalue  i see is : "%s"' % Adcmsg)
    led.value  = Adcmsg # led value is equql to the Adsmsg data.
```

def main(args=None):
rclpy.init(args=args)

```
minimal_subscriber = MinimalSubscriber()

rclpy.spin(minimal_subscriber)

# Destroy the node explicitly
# (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
# when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
minimal_subscriber.destroy_node()
rclpy.shutdown()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
main()

but i get error like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/pyeng_adcpubsub/talk", line 33, in 
sys.exit(load_entry_point('pyeng-adcpubsub==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'talk')())
File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyeng_adcpubsub/adctalk.py", line 60, in main
adctalk = Adctalk()
File "/home/test1/ros2_ws/install/pyeng_adcpubsub/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyeng_adcpubsub/adctalk.py", line 30, in **init**
self.Adcpub_= self.create_publisher(Int32,pot, 10)
File "/opt/ros/iron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rclpy/node.py", line 1469, in create_publisher
final_topic = self.resolve_topic_name(topic)
File "/opt/ros/iron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rclpy/node.py", line 1422, in resolve_topic_name
return _rclpy.rclpy_resolve_name(self.handle, topic, only_expand, False)
TypeError: rclpy_resolve_name(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. (arg0: rclpy::Node, arg1: str, arg2: bool, arg3: bool) -> str

Invoked with: <rclpy._rclpy_pybind11.Node object at 0xffff9596c5f0>, 0, False, False
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1

can someone help?

Comment: Please format your code correctly, so that it is readable and fix any typos and slang. If you need hints on how to format, please refer to the edit, that was kindly made by jsotola, on your previous question. Thank you.